# how do you trigger the virtual keyboard on mobile devices with javascript?

Tags: javascript

i heard someone say

> If you trigger the .focus() from within a .click() event (e.g. from opening your dialog), the keyboard shows up

can someone elaborate on this?

if this is a dupe, can someone direct me to a question **exactly** like this with an answer?

right now im using `var a = !document.elementFromPoint(document.querySelector("textarea").getBoundingClientRect().x, document.querySelector("textarea").getBoundingClientRect().y).dispatchEvent("click");`

Comment: It means if you have an text input field and you call `click()` on it, the virtual keyboard opens.

Comment: @WaisKamal i tryed it but it dosent work on textarea

Comment: i think i know what you mean: first though: does this work in textarea also? second, if yes: is this like <textarea onclick="focusMe()"></textarea> <script> function focusMe() { document.querySelector("textarea").focus(); } </script>

Comment: Yes it doesn't work on texareas (only on buttons I guess). The only solution I can think of is getting the textarea coordinates with `getBoundingClientRect()` then dispatching a click event on the textarea using these coordinates.

Comment: @WaisKamal can you show me how to do this you are suggesting?

Comment: Search for how to dispatch a click event on an element and how to use getBoundingClientRect to get the coordinates of an element.

Comment: i know how, but how to combine getBoundingClientRect() and dispatchEvent()?

Comment: If you read about both you will know how. Basically you can use coordinates in dispatch event.

Comment: this method dosent work

Comment: It does work. If it does not work for you, open a new question showing the code you;ve tried.

Comment: @WaisKamal can you show me your code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231751/discussion-between-cooldude1058-and-wais-kamal).